# GeoServer Layer Preview Stopped Working

Tags: geoserver

I got GeoServer up and running today and created a store that is linked to my postgis database, with a layer corresponding to one of the tables in the database. I then previewed the layer using the GeoServer Layer Previewer and it all worked nicely.

I began messing around with GeoServer, trying to get this layer plotted on my own OpenLayers map, and now none of the layers work in the Layer Previewer. When I click "go", a new tab opens with a blank box where the map should be, and the tab indicates that it is loading. However, it does not ever appear to load correctly.

Does anybody have any idea what I might have done to mess this up?

Thanks,

-Rob

Comment: How big is the layer?  It might be worth restarting Geoserver to see if that helps.  sudo /etc.init.d/geoserver restart on a linux box.

Comment: test previewing the layer in png or any other static format. Do you see a result, or an error message? If you get a blank image your layer's bounding box might be off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be a couple of different things as far as styles go. It might be worth looking at the page source and the url of the request to see if any parameters are missing. You could also use the inspector or page editor tools, and look at whether the url is giving any error codes through the network tab.